# How to handle stateChangeStart event at controller level in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to redirect to home page when specific views are refreshed in browser. If I handle stateChangeStart event on rootScope level, it all works fine and navigates to home page.

```
    var payApp = angular.module('pay', ['ui.router', 'pay.controllers', 'pay.services', 'exceptionOverride']);

    payApp.run(['$templateCache', '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$window', '$location', function ($templateCache, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $window, $location) {

    $templateCache.put(baseUrl, angular.element('#ui-view').html());

    // Allows to retrieve UI Router state information from inside templates
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState) {

        // Sets the layout name, which can be used to display different layouts (header, footer etc.)
        // based on which page the user is located
        $rootScope.layout = toState.layout;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {

        //When payment or order page is refreshed, navigate to home
        if (fromState.name == '' && (toState.name == 'payment' || toState.name == 'order')) {
            $location.url('/');
        }
    });

    var windowElement = angular.element($window);
    windowElement.on('beforeunload', function (event) {

        var path = $location.path();

        if (path == '/payment' || path == '/order') {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}]);
```

But I am trying to move this logic to a specific controller level so the stateChangeStart event will be fired only for specific views which are using this controller.

```
var payControllers = angular.module('pay.controllers', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngIdle']);

 payControllers.controller('payPaymentCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$window', '$location', 'payDataService', 'Idle', 'Keepalive', '$uibModal', 
  function ($scope, $state, $window, $location, service, Idle, Keepalive, $uibModal) {

      var windowElement = angular.element($window);
      windowElement.on('beforeunload', function (event) {

          var path = $location.path();

          if (path == '/payment' || path == '/paymentcreated') {
              event.preventDefault();
          }
      });


    $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {

        //When payment or order page is refreshed, navigate to home
        //Both payment and order share the same controller.
        if (fromState.name == '' && (toState.name == 'payment' || toState.name == 'order')) {
            $location.url('/');
        }
    });

      $scope.paymentOption = service.GetpaymentOption();

      if ($scope.paymentOption == null) {
          //$state.go('home', {}, { reload: true });
          //$location.path('/').replace();
          $location.url('/');
      }
   }]);
```

The beforeunload event fires in the controller when a view is refreshed in browser but stateChangeStart does not fire.
Also, I tried to get rid of the stateChangeStart event from the controller level and handle to go to home page when some crucial data is missing. It gives me an error saying "Unable to load property of undefined". It appears to be trying to load some data that is bound to angular scope elements which usually appears upon some operation on home page. I need it to look like just the way when I open the home page for the first time when the application is run.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you try to use `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', ...);` within the controller?

Comment: I just tried to use $rootScope within controller and the event did not fire. Thanks.

Comment: The event fires for other actions such as navigating to a different view upon certain actions on the page but not when I refresh using F5. Is there any other event that can capture the refresh? Thanks.